# Does Django is models property hit the database more than once?

Tags: python, django, django-models, singleton

I've searched in several places but I haven't found a satisfactory answer anywhere.

I have these models:

App `bar`

```py
    class Bar(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_lenth=50)
        text = models.TextField()
```

App `xyz`

```py
    class Xyz(models.Model):
        bar = models.ForeingKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Bar')
```

App `foo`

```py
    class Foo(models.Model):
        xyz = models.OneToOneField(Xyz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Xyz')
        
        def bar_name(self):
            return self.xyz.bar.name

        def bar_text(self):
            return self.xyz.bar.text
```

My first question is, on `self.xyz.bar.name` and on `self.xyz.bar.text` does hit in the database?

If yes, how can i optimize it?

---

I already tried this, but I'm not sure if it improves anything:

```py
    def bar_name(self):
        return Xyz.objects.select_related('bar').get(pk=self.xyz_id).bar.name

    def bar_text(self):
        return Xyz.objects.select_related('bar').get(pk=self.xyz_id).bar.text
```

And here comes my second question, using `select_related()`, I would create a single method like Sigleton pattern, something like this:

```py
    def singleton_bar(self):
        return Xyz.objects.select_related('bar').get(pk=self.xyz_id)

    def bar_name(self):
        return self.singleton_bar().bar.name

    def bar_text(self):
        return self.singleton_bar().bar.text
```

Comment: Have you tried using django-query-profiler?

Comment: I assume that when you say "App `bar`" etc., you really mean "Model `bar`". Now, to see what queries Django makes and experiment with reducing them it is a good idea to use the Django Debug Toolbar.

Comment: @Humberto Vieira, the approach of using the `select_related` in the query is not the best IMO. You must do the `select_related` wherever you load the `Foo` class. For instance, i.e. `Foo.objects.filter(...).select_related('xyz__bar')`. Then, accessing the property won't hit the database again because you've already loaded those relations. i'll write up an answer if you think this was helpful

Comment: @AntonisChristofides Yes, I put "App `foo`" just to indicate that they are from different models and apps, without being in the same `models.py` file. I don't know if this could interfere with anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My first question is, on `self.xyz.bar.name` and on `self.xyz.bar.text` does hit in the database?

**Yes**, given these are not loaded yet by some other query. If you query for `self.xyz.bar.name`, and `xyz` is not loaded yet, it will make *two* queries: one to fetch the `xyz` object, and one to fetch the `bar` object referenced by that `xyz` object.

If you thus access both `.bar_name()` and `.bar_text()`, it will *not* make four queries, since the data is loaded by the first method call, and the second one will "piggy back" on the work already done by the first one.

> If yes, how can [I] optimize it?

I would advise *not* to optimize the queries in the methods, since here you will each time make the same query, as a result with your second approacy, if you call `.bar_name()` twice, it will two times make the same query. You simply should load the `Foo` object efficiently. Indeed, you can obtain the `foo` object with:

```
foo = Foo.objects.select_related('xyz__bar').get(pk=42)
```

This will make `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s in the query, to load the related `xyz` and `xyz.bar` object in the same query, and thus will result in no extra querying.

Comment: I could replace this load `foo` in return of `def singleton_bar(self):`, like: `return Foo.objects.select_related('xyz__bar').get(pk=self.id)` or that would not be recommended?

Comment: @HumbertoVieira: no, since it means that for each method call, you will again make such query. The idea is that Django lazily follows `ForeignKey`s, but once loaded, these can be reused, so by making the `singleton_bar()` logic, you basically prevent using Django's caching mechanism to reuse data if it is queried already somehow.

Comment: Oh right.. So I having a `serializers.py` I could load `foo` efficiently, and inside a serializer class get the values of `bar_name` and `bar_text ` more quickly

Comment: @HumbertoVieira: yes indeed. Usually you specify the `.select_related(...)` in the `queryset` of a `ModelViewSet` or some `APIView`.

Comment: If it's not asking too much, could you show me an example of a `ModelViewSet` and `ModelSerializer` where I can get the value of `bar_name` and `bar_text` more efficiently?
Because if I put the `queryset` with the `.select_related(...)` clause in `ModelViewSet`, I don't know how to declare it correctly in `ModelSerializer` to get this values

Comment: @HumbertoVieira: just user `queryset = Foo.objects.select_related('xyz__bar')`