# How to serialize data more efficiently in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-rest-viewsets

The part of my problem is solved by the question: [#72534250](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534250/does-django-is-models-property-hit-the-database-more-than-once)
I understood that the path I was following was wrong, and I should change the optimization of the models to serializers and/or viewsets.
**But how?**

I had this structure:
*I already removed `element_name` and `element_text` from Models `Foo`

```py
    class User(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_lenth=50)
        age = models.IntergerField()
```

```py
    class Customer(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeingKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='User')
```

```py
    class Element(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_lenth=50)
        text = models.TextField()
```

```py
    class Bar(models.Model):
        element = models.ForeingKey(Element, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Element')
```

```py
    class Foo(models.Model):
        bar = models.OneToOneField(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Bar')
        customer = models.ForeingField(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Customer')
        is_active = models.BooleanField('Is Active', default=False)
        
        def user(self):
            return self.customer.user
        
        # Removed
        def element_name(self):
            return self.bar.element.name

        # Removed
        def element_text(self):
            return self.bar.element.text
```

And these serializers:

```py
    class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = '__all__'
```

```py
    class CustomerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Customer
            fields = '__all__'
```

```py
    class ElementSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Element
            fields = '__all__'
```

```py
    class BarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        element = ElementSerializer()

        class Meta:
            model = Bar
            fields = '__all__'
```

```py
    class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        bar = BarSerializer()
        user = UserSerializer()
        
        class Meta:
            model = Foo
            fields = '__all__'
```

And this viewset:

```py
    class FooViewSet(ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = FooSerializer
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
        http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch']

        def get_queryset(self):
           active = self.request.query_params.get('is_active', False)
           name = self.request.query_params.get('name', '')
           data = {'is_active': active}
           if name == 'Fire':
              data['bar__element__name'] = name
           queryset = Foo.objects.filter(**data)
           return queryset
```

I try this [tutorial](http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/), but I didn't notice any real performance improvement. So I'm looking for another way to solve this problem.

I thought... If I just put `select_related(...)` in the return of `get_queryset`, how Django Rest would identify that it is to serialize the cached data? Would that really improve performance?

I also need `element_name`, `element_text` and object `user` to be returned in the GET of `FooViewSet`. How can I return them in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how Django Rest would identify that it is to serialize
> the cached data? Would that really improve performance?

All the data that has been fetched by `select_related` are in your model object instances. So since the serializers as well as the model properties you defined essentially use these instances, they will have access to this "cached" data directly.

> I also need element_name, element_text and object user to be returned in the GET of FooViewSet. How can I return them in the most efficient way?

In line with this, you can get them all in one query (including what `element_name` and `element_text` needs)  with:

```py
queryset = Foo.objects.select_related(
    "bar__element",
    "customer__user",
).filter(**data)
```